# How do I increase an app’s width using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, window-manager

While we're using an application that is not in full-size mode, we can double click the right edge of its window to maximize its width along the right side. This also works similarly when we double click the left edge.

I wanted know if there exists or if we can create a keyboard shortcut for this behavior?

Comment: Editors:  Do not change the meaning of the question!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [Rectangle App](https://rectangleapp.com).  IMO, windows management has been a weak spot in OS X/macOS for eons. I found this App fairly strong in filling in the missing pieces.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible on MacOS out-of-the-box but it's possible to assign a shortcut for moving a window to the left/right side of the screen (the window will take half of the screen). Are you ok with such solution?

Answer (score 0):

While there is a keyboard shortcut to minimise any window (<kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>), there isn't a default one to maximise any.

---

However, there is another way to maximise any window (other than double clicking the app's title bar) as explained in [Manage app windows on Mac - Maximise or minimise app windows](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp2469/mac):

> *Maximise a window:* Press and hold the Option key while you click the green button [image: green button] in the top-left corner of an app window. To return to the previous window size, Option-click the button again.

---

You could also go to *System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts* and set a shortcut named "Zoom" with a custom keyboard shortcut (e.g. <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) assigned to all applications. (See [this old thread](https://superuser.com/questions/718600/keyboard-shortcut-to-maximize-current-window-application-in-osx) - but still working solution - for details)